# GCC unexpected warning?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I was working on a personal project and I made this kind of code (in a static little helper function) :

```c
char *tmp = NULL;
if ((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b') != NULL) && tmp - mode < 3) return BINARY_MODE;
else // ...
```

Then when I tried to compile with GCC 12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1), I had this warning :

```
warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   31 |     if ((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b') != NULL) && tmp - mode < 3) return BINARY_MODE;
      |              ^
```

The only thing I tried that solved the problem (at least that suppressed the warning) was to assign the return value of strchr before the conditional.
Is this a bug or did I just miss something ? In both cases the resulting program was working as I expected though.

### EDIT

Due to the fact that I should have let the initial code I posted (that wasn't the code I wanted to post), here is the previous one (that was actually good), so everyone can understand the different answers :

```c
char *tmp = NULL;
if ((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b')) != NULL && tmp - mode < 3) return BINARY_MODE;
else // ...
```

Comment: The error you show doesn't match the code you show. This is why it's so important to create a proper [mre], that you copy-paste into the question (not re-type).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh yeah my bad I'm actually stupid. Thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah btw I will re-edit it I've more parentheses than I did in my code

Comment: Don't alter the question so that the answers you've got are invalid.  The code only worked by accident — not because the code was correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler don't worry I just moved the parenthese on the spot it was initially

Comment: That invalidates my answer — I said you claim to have one thing, and now you claim to have something different.  It's frustrating!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it does not invalidate your answer

Comment: Actually, it did; I had to be a lot more verbose to make my answer valid again.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If I didn't edit my initial code, that wouldn't have fit what I initially did wrong, and what the compiler warning says. First thing I wrote in my post was " if ((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b')) != NULL && ... " (which is good and not what I wanted to write, since my code wasn't good)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this subexpression:

```
(tmp = strchr(mode, 'b') != NULL)
```

The inequality operator `!=` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  So the above is equivalent to:

```
(tmp = (strchr(mode, 'b') != NULL))
```

Which means you're assigning the result of a comparison, which has type `int` and results in the values 0 or 1, and assigning that to a `char *`, which is why you're getting the warning.

You need to add parenthesis to perform the assignment first:

```
((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b')) != NULL)
```

Comment: This - assignment first, then comparison. Otherwise warning that you may have mistakenly used `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Thanks you all, I completely forgot this rule of precedence

Answer (score 1):

#### Before the question was hacked

The compiler is seeing:

```
if ((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b') != NULL) && tmp - mode < 3) return BINARY_MODE;
```

You are claiming you have:

```
if ((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b')) != NULL && tmp - mode < 3) return BINARY_MODE;
```

Notice the difference in the number of close parentheses `)` after the `'b'` and after `NULL`.  What you claim you've got is the correct code — now you need to make sure that's what the compiler sees.

#### After the question was hacked

The compiler is still seeing the erroneous code, but you now admit that you gave it the erroneous code.

That code is equivalent to writing:

```
if ((tmp = (strchr(mode, 'b') != NULL)) && tmp - mode < 3) return BINARY_MODE;
```

which assigns the result of the comparison to `tmp` — assigning an `int` to a `char *` as the compiler complains in the error message.

The correct code is what you originally claimed to have.  You need to ensure that the assignment is compared with null, not the result of calling `strchr()`.

So, the fix is to write:

```
if ((tmp = strchr(mode, 'b')) != NULL && tmp - mode < 3) return BINARY_MODE;
```

The code 'appeared' to work because you assigned either `0` or `1` to `tmp`, and then subtracting the `mode` pointer from that gives a negative `ptrdiff_t` value, and that result is negative, and hence less than 3.  I think you probably tested with `b` present and not with `b` absent.